# Unique Hahn Banach (norm preserving) extensions for $c_0$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I need to show that any continuous linear functional on $c_0$ has a unique Hahn Banach extension (i.e. norm of the functional is preserved) to a continuous linear functional on $l^{\infty}$. Here $c_0$ is the space of all sequences converging to $0$.

Now using the fact that $(c_0)^* = l^1$, we can easily get *a* norm preserving extension on $l^{\infty}$. I am having difficulty in showing how it must be unique.

Comment: I was not aware of it, while posting the question.

Comment: I found a reference to a certain article by Harmand et al, $1993$: look [here](https://books.google.hr/books?id=YMpoDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA110&lpg=PA110&dq=harmand+et+al+1993+normed&source=bl&ots=02uqlpEwAR&sig=O1rEW7cghi61fi0BLvJJNUFXOP4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjOtvvmr6zWAhWB2RoKHTp3AowQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=harmand%20et%20al%201993%20normed&f=false). I couldn't find the article itself, though.

Comment: @mechanodroid possible duplicate, but without answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/589395/how-can-i-show-that-given-a-norm-one-linear-functional-on-c-0-that-there-is-a