# Show that the Hahn Banach extension is unique.

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $X = \ell_{\infty}$ and $Y = c_0$, considered as a subspace of $X$. How can I show that if $y^{\ast}\in Y^{\ast}$ and $ \| y^{\ast}\| = 1$, then the norm preserving Hahn Banach extension is unique?

Comment: Some questions for clarification: do you want $Y$ to be $c_0$, the space of sequences which tend to $0$ with the sup norm, and $X$ to be $Y^{**}$? Also, what do you mean by "the norm preserving Hahn-Banach extension"? What functional are you extending, to what space?

Comment: what i mean is Y as a subspace of X and by Hahn Banach theorem, we can extend $y^{\ast}$ to $x^{\ast}$ defined on X such that their norm equal.

Comment: What makes you think that it is unique?

Comment: This appears to be false. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2992237/343481.

Comment: This is an exercise given by my prof, I was having a lot of troubles trying to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that $y^*$ can be identified with $y \in \ell^1$ and this generates the functional
$g : x \mapsto \sum_{i = 1}^\infty x_i y_i$
for $x \in \ell^\infty$.

Now, suppose that $f \in X^*$ is a different extension with the same norm. Then, $f - g$ vanishes on $c_0$. However, there must be $\hat x \in \ell^\infty$ with
$$(f-g)(\hat x) = 1.$$

Even more, let $T_n$ be the operator that sets the first elements of a sequence to zero. Then,
$$(f-g)(T_n \hat x) = (f-g)(\hat x) = 1.$$
However, $g(T_n \hat x) \to 0$ and, thus, $f(T_n \hat x) \to 1$.
Finally, we consider for $k \in \mathbb N$ the sequence $z_k$ with entries
$$
(z_k)_n
=
\begin{cases}
K\,\operatorname{sign}(y_n)& \text{for } n < k, \\
\hat x_n&\text{else},
\end{cases}
$$
Where $K = \|\hat x\|_{\ell^\infty}$.
Then, 
$$f(z_k) \to K \, \| y \|_{\ell^1} + 1.$$
However, $\|z_k\|_{\ell^\infty} \le K$. This contradicts that $\|f\|_{X^\star} = \|y\|_{\ell^1}$.